# How to copy and paste a large excel file(27MB) using python faster?

Tags: python, excel

While using this code, it takes hours to copy and paste data from one excel sheet(27k rows and 100s of columns) to a specific sheet of another excel file. Is there any better ways to speed up the process?

```
import openpyxl as xl;
filename ="C:\\Users\\livin.vincent\\OneDrive - Automation Anywhere\\Desktop\\New folder\\New Microsoft Excel.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
filename1 ="C:\\Users\\livin.vincent\\OneDrive - Automation Anywhere\\Desktop\\New folder\\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Comment: `shutil.copy()` maybe? https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell Since OP is opening the destination workbook and only processing the zeroth worksheet, we might want to assume there's other data in the destination file that shouldn't be clobbered.

Comment: @AKX I guess it's a possibility. OP should be able to work it out hopefully... and maybe be a bit more specific about what they want to do in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MarkSetchell
Actually I need to copy a particular worksheet from an excel file to a specific sheet in another excel file.

Answer (score 2):

If just raw file copying (as suggested by Mark Setchell) is not an option, you can speed things up by opening the source workbook as read-only and by using `iter_rows`:

```
source_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx", read_only=True)
dest_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test2.xlsx")
source_ws = source_wb.worksheets[0]
dest_ws = dest_wb.worksheets[0]

for y, row in enumerate(source_ws.iter_rows(values_only=True), 1):
    for x, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        dest_ws.cell(y, x).value = value
```

For a workbook of 500x500 cells, this seems to be about 20% faster (including file IO time).

## Even more performance?!

If you're willing to dig a little deeper into the internals of openpyxl, this seems to eke out a little more performance still (25% faster than the original, profiler's telling me most of the time is spent parsing XML)

Note I only tried this with numbers, so it could well do weird things with e.g. dates (but we're used to Excel doing that, aren't we...).

```
def fast_readonly_ws_parse(ws: ReadOnlyWorksheet):
    with contextlib.closing(ws._get_source()) as src:
        parser = WorkSheetParser(
            src,
            ws._shared_strings,
            data_only=True,
            epoch=ws.parent.epoch,
            date_formats=ws.parent._date_formats,
        )
        for idx, row in parser.parse():
            yield (idx, [cell['value'] for cell in row])

# ...

source_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx", read_only=True)
dest_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test2.xlsx")
source_ws = source_wb.worksheets[0]
dest_ws = dest_wb.worksheets[0]
for y, row in fast_readonly_ws_parse(source_ws):
    for x, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        dest_ws.cell(y, x).value = value
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @AKX . But I need much more faster operation. So integrated excel macro and now it is working faster.